# When I try to write a file the last row of the file was not fully generated

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a file from Database.

I have used the following code

record=row wise record from DB

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(record);
 protected FileStream fs=new FileStream("C:\workarea\exports", FileMode.Open);;
 fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

The above code has generated the file accordingly with the DB instead of the last row of the file.some part of the last line was missing here.

Please suggest me what mistake I have done here.

Thanks
Soumen

Comment: First off, this is not valid C#. Lastly, you need to dispose your stream to flush everything. Read up on resource clean up in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Add resource cleanup and you should be good to go.

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(record);
 using(var fs = new FileStream("C:\workarea\exports", FileMode.Open))
     fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```